# Convert x-axis from days to month in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**i have x-axis which is in terms of days (366 days Feb was taken as 29 days) but instead I want to convert it in terms of months (Jan - Dec). What should i do...**

```
def plotGraph():
    line, point = getXY()
    
    plt.plot(line['xlMax'], c='orangered', alpha=0.5, label = 'Minimum Temperature (2005-14)')
    plt.plot(line['xlMin'], c='dodgerblue', alpha=0.5, label = 'Minimum Temperature (2005-14)')
    
    plt.scatter(point['xsMax'].index, point['xsMax'], s = 10, c = 'maroon', label = 'Record Break Minimum (2015)')
    plt.scatter(point['xsMin'].index, point['xsMin'], s = 10, c = 'midnightblue', label = 'Record Break Maximum (2015)')
    
    ax1 = plt.gca() # Primary axes
    
    ax1.fill_between(line['xlMax'].index , line['xlMax'], line['xlMin'], facecolor='lightgray', alpha=0.25)
     
    ax1.grid(True, alpha = 1)
    
    for spine in ax1.spines:
        ax1.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
        
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_alpha(0.3)
    
    # Removing Ticks
    ax1.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both',length=0)
    
    plt.show()
```

[image: This is how the graph looks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the quickest change might be to just set new ticks and tick labels at the starts of months; I found the conversion from day-of-the-year to month [here, the first table](https://cals.arizona.edu/AZMET/doy.htm):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = range(1,367)
y = np.random.rand(len(range(1,367)))

ax.plot(x,y)

month_starts = [1,32,61,92,122,153,183,214,245,275,306,336]
month_names = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
               'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'] 

ax.set_xticks(month_starts)
ax.set_xticklabels(month_names)
```

[image]

Note I assumed your days were numbered 1 to 366; if they are 0 to 365 you may have to change the `range`.

**But I think usually a better approach** is to get your days into some sort of `datetime`; this is more flexible and usually pretty smart.  If say, your days were not confined to one year, it would be more complicated to associate day numbers with months.

This example uses `datetime` instead of integers.  The dates are plotted on the x-axis directly, and then the `DateFormatter` and `MonthLocator` from `matplotlib.dates` are used to format the axis appropriately:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

start = dt.datetime(2016,1,1)    #there has to be a year given, even if it isn't plotted
new_dates = [start + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(366)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = new_dates
y = np.random.rand(len(range(1,367)))

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

ax.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: that definitely works... I will wait for a better approach, and if I don't get one, than I will assume there is no other way and select your answer. Thanks man !!

Comment: See my edit!  Added what I think is the best way to do it

Comment: This kind of approach is what I was looking for, Thanks again !!   (b ᵔ▽ᵔ)b