# How to convert number indexes into months and display them onto a plot without changing the structure of a plot in python?

Tags: python, data-science

I need to display months on x axis of a plot instead of the indexes number of a data frame that goes from 1 to 365, which they represent the number of day of the year. So instead of an x-axis which goes from 1 to 365, I want to display it as "Jan", "Feb" and so on, without losing the structure of the plot.

Here is the main structure of my data frame:

```
    Month   Day Max_Data    Min_Data    MonthDay
1   1       1   1.1        -13.3        1-1
2   1       2   3.9        -12.2        1-2
3   1       3   3.9        -6.7         1-3
4   1       4   4.4        -8.8         1-4
5   1      5    2.8        -15.5        1-5
```

I am currently plotting using:

```
plt.scatter(data_2015.index, data_2015['Max_Data'], marker='^', color='green',s=40, alpha=1.0)
```

And if I changed `data_2015.index` to `Month` the graph will plot a different a completely wrong values, as they 28, 30 or 31 rows for each month.

So what is the way to convert indexes into month and display them into the x axis of a plot?

Comment: do you want your x-axis to go from "Jan" to "Dec", each month included only one time (12 values) or do you want 31x "Jan", 28x "Feb", 31 x "Mar", 30 x "Apr" an so on (365 values)

Comment: No. Each month one time.

Comment: and which value do you want to be plotted for each month? Some kind of aggregated value like mean, min, max for the corresponding month?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by doing simply the following:

```
month_starts = [0,31,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335]
month_names = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
               'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'] 
plt.gca().set_xticks(month_starts)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(month_names)
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360855/convert-x-axis-from-days-to-month-in-matplotlib?answertab=active#tab-top) on stack overflow.